# Can i deploy a WiX setup using the Microsoft ClickOnce technology?

Tags: wix, clickonce

I have a Wix setup created for my windows form application and i have a server to publish it . Earlier projects were published using ClickOnce application. Can i do that with my Wix setup too where the setup created would be integrated with the clickonce application. The user will click on the url and it will download only the setup.exe and when clicked on it , it will install the application according to the setting done in wix. I dont even know if the question is correct.

Comment: I figured you can't do that. WiX and ClickOnce are different ways of deploying the applications. I Found a good deal of info from the msdn page. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/142dbbz4(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that.

"ClickOnce application is any Windows Presentation Foundation, Windows Forms, or console application published using ClickOnce technology. You can publish a ClickOnce application in three different ways: from a Web page, from a network file share, or from media such as a CD-ROM."

Comment: Yes. Thank you. The msdn explained everything very nicely. Although for this particular use case i found ClickOnce useful, i think WiX is the way to go in future for larger projects. But the best part about click once is that is gives you a webpage and the auuto updating feature.

Comment: Yes, this technology is perfect for you. There is a great pluralsight course regarding clickonce, it help me much.

Comment: For people not looking in the comments for answers i suggest you mark the question as answered. :)